# Split a line into parts at a certain vertex

Tags: qgis

I want to split up my line feature in three parts at the marked vertex in the added image. Is there a solution?

[image: vertex]

Comment: You can always use the `advanced digitizing toolbar`.

Comment: okay worked out for me, thank you.